# Quiero extraer de la BD solo las publicaciones que ha realizado el propietario del perfil

Tags: php, sql

Estoy intentado extraer solo las publicaciones que ha realizado el propietario del perfil de usuario pero en vez de eso me esta haciendo todo lo contrario y esta extrayendo todas las publicaciones que han hecho todos los usuarios que hay registrado en la **Red Social**.

### Código SQL:

```
SELECT users.id_user, users.name, users.surname, users.photo_profile, publication.id_pub, publication.id_user_pub, publication.messeger_pub, publication.photo_pub, publication.create_at_pub FROM publication INNER JOIN users WHERE users.id_user = publication.id_user_pub ORDER BY publication.id_pub DESC LIMIT 10
```

Tengo el id del propietario del perfil almacenado en una variable `$user` y mi propio **id** de usuario almacenada en una variable llamada `$id`

He intentado hacer esto WHERE `publication.id_user_pub = $user` pero me saca todas las publicaciones de todos modos con la particularidad que me las repite por cada usuario registrado en la Base de datos.

Y problema un poco extraño pero espero que ustedes puedan ayudarme a solucionar este problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer una relación de tablas es necesario incluir la sentencia `ON`, la cual le indica a la base de datos como se relacionan esas tablas.

```
INNER JOIN users ON users.id_user = publication.id_user_pub
```

Una vez teniendo esa relación puedes filtar el usuario que te interesa

```
WHERE publication.id_user_pub = $user
```

Tu consulta quedaría como

```
SELECT 
  users.id_user,
  users.name,
  users.surname,
  users.photo_profile,
  publication.id_pub,
  publication.id_user_pub,
  publication.messeger_pub,
  publication.photo_pub,
  publication.create_at_pub 
FROM
  publication 
  INNER JOIN users ON users.id_user = publication.id_user_pub 
WHERE publication.id_user_pub = $user
ORDER BY publication.id_pub DESC 
LIMIT 10
```